# Translating a line from Mallarmé

Tags: grammaire

Is Mallarmé omitting the third person plural pronoun here?  Here's the original passage:

> Des séraphins en pleurs
> Rêvant, l'archet aux doigts, dans le calme des fleurs
> Vaporeuses, tiraient de mourantes violes
> De blancs sanglots glissant sur l'azur des corolles.

In normal prose would this be:

> [Ils] rêvant Des séraphins en pleurs, l'archet aux doigts, dans le calme des fleurs
> Vaporeuses.  [Ils] tiraient de mourantes violes, de blancs sanglots, glissant sur l'azur des corolles.

Also, is 'glissant' a gerundive here or is it a 3rd person present indicative verb?  I'm guessing the former in which case the translation would be:

> They're dreaming of weeping seraphim, the bending of the fingers, among the calm of the vaporous flowers, taking the white sobs of dying viols sliding into the blue of their coronas.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 5):

> La lune s’attristait. Des séraphins en pleurs
>
> Rêvant, l’archet aux doigts, dans le calme des fleurs
>
> Vaporeuses, tiraient de mourantes violes
>
> De blancs sanglots glissant sur l’azur des corolles

Here's my translation:

> The moon grew sad. Seraphim in tears,
>
> Dreaming, bows at their fingertips, in the calm
>
> Of the mist-covered flowers, drew from dying viols
>
> Blank sobs that slid on the [corollas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petal#Corolla)' blue.

No, there's nothing missing syntactically that I would have to supply. The core clause reads:

> Des séraphins tiraient des sanglots des violes.

If we want to include all the clauses but leave out the troublesome qualifiers, we could get a bare structure like this:

> Des séraphins, rêvant, l'archet aux doigts, tiraient des sanglots des violes.

Now apply a poetic inversion between the sobs and the viols, and reinsert all the descriptive parts, and you have the structure seen in the poem.

The reason for the inversion is that it would be awkward to qualify the *sanglots* as *glissant sur l'azur des corolles* and only introduce the source of the *sanglots* afterwards, so instead we get the shorter phrase (*des violes*) out of the way first.

Comment: But I don't understand how 'seraphins' can be a subject when it is preceded by 'des'.  Am I understanding 'des' correctly?  Wouldn't that be like in English saying 'of seraphim'?  Doesn't 'des' mean 'of'?

Comment: @bobsmith76 There are two *des*. One is indeed the preposition + article "from the". The other is the partitive article "some". In this case it's the partitive article. *Je vois des séraphins* ; *Des séraphins sont là !*

Comment: Cool, got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Des", here, would be omitted in English. It would mean "several seraphins", "some seraphins", that is to say... "Seraphins".